# How to create button without any layout for Android App in Android Studio

Tags: android

Actually I need some button or buttons over the "In Call UI" such that all the Call Controls are accessible at the same time.

Comment: you can create any layout through java code also.No need of xml for that

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I am new to Java and Android Studio. Further explanation over the query. I need a floating button over the Incoming / Outgoing Call Notification screen. Just a button or buttons and nothing else such that the rest of the Call Notification Screen UI remain accessible. An elaborated answer with any guidance link will be highly helpful

Comment: If you haven't started or able to change your code just create a use blank activity template provided by android studio to create new activity. It has default implementation of floating button with it

Comment: You post is low quality. Please add exisiting code, screenshots, drawings anything which might be helpful to us ;-)